# What is the form of the conformal covariance equation in a 2D Lorentzian CFT?

Tags: conformal-field-theory, causality, covariance

The naive expectation is that a $2D$ Lorentzian correlator should obey a covariance equation of the form

$$A_n(z_{i})=\Bigg(\prod_i (c z_i+d)^{h_i}(\bar{c}\bar{z}_i+\bar{d})^{\bar{h}_i}\Bigg)A_n\Big(\frac{az+b}{cz+d}\Big) \tag{1}$$

however, due to $\pm i\epsilon$ prescriptions featuring inside of correlators (which are inserted in order to give the theory a causal structure) the correlators no longer obey this covariance equation.

My question/request is: *write down the correct covariance equation for a $2D$ Lorentzian CFT. i.e. what is the correct form of (1)?*

Background to question that can be skipped:

I am aware that the correct covariance equation should involve the **universal cover** of the conformal group of $2D$ Minkowski space $\tilde{SO}(2,2)$[1], and that one should consider the theory as living on the **universal cover** of Minkowski space $\tilde{\mathbb{R}}^{1,1}$(i.e. the entire Lorentzian cylinder and not just a single Minkowski patch thereof). Both of these enhancements are necessary for the theory to admit a causal structure. However the literature on the universal cover of $SO(2,2)$ is hard to decipher, so I do not know how exactly one labels the elements of this group, which is a necessary first step for writing down covariance equations for correlators which transform under this group.

Example: The Wightman two point function for scalars of conformal dimension $\Delta$ with a chosen operator ordering $1,2$ reads,
\begin{align}
\langle \mathcal{O}(z_1)\mathcal{O}(z_2)\rangle=\frac{1}{\Big(z_{12}\bar{z}_{12}-i\epsilon_{+}(\bar{z}_{12}-z_{12})\Big)^{\Delta}}\\
=\frac{1}{|z_{12}\bar{z}_{12}|^{\Delta}}\times\begin{cases}1,&z_{12}\bar{z}_{12}>0\\
e^{i\pi\Delta}, &z_{12}\bar{z}_{12}<0\, ,\,  \bar{z}_{12}>z_{12}\\
e^{-i\pi\Delta}, &z_{12}\bar{z}_{12}<0\, ,\,  \bar{z}_{12}<z_{12}
\end{cases}\tag{2}
\end{align}
One can check that (2) does not satisfy the naive covariance equation (1) specifically for conformal transformations which change the causal relations between points $1$ and $2$. For example, if points $1,2$ are spacelike separated $z_{12}\bar{z}_{12}>0$ and we perform a conformal transformation which brings $1$ into the forward lightcone of $2$, $z_{12}\bar{z}_{12}<0\,\text{&}\,\bar{z}_{12}>z_{12}$, then on the LHS of $(1)$ we have,

\begin{equation}
A_2(z_i)\vert_{z_{12}\bar{z}_{12}>0}=\frac{1}{|z_{12}\bar{z}_{12}|^{\Delta}}\tag{3}
\end{equation}

whereas on the RHS of (1) we have (to avoid clutter we define $\alpha=\prod_{i=1,2} (c z_i+d)$ and $\bar{\alpha}=\prod_{i=1,2}(\bar{c}\bar{z}_i+\bar{d})$)

\begin{align*}
\alpha^{-\Delta} \bar{\alpha}^{-\Delta} A_2\Big(\frac{az+b}{cz+d}\Big) &=\frac{\alpha^{-\Delta}\bar{\alpha}^{-\Delta}}{\Big(\frac{z_{12}\bar{z}_{12}}{\alpha\bar{\alpha}}-i\epsilon_{+}(\frac{\bar{z}_{12}}{\bar{\alpha}}-\frac{z_{12}}{\alpha})\Big)^{\Delta}}\tag{4}\\
&=\frac{1}{|z_{12}\bar{z}_{12}|^{\Delta}}\frac{\alpha^{-\Delta}\bar{\alpha}^{-\Delta}}{\Big(\frac{1}{\alpha\bar{\alpha}}-i\epsilon_{+}(\frac{\bar{z}_{12}}{\bar{\alpha}}-\frac{z_{12}}{\alpha})\Big)^{\Delta}}\tag{5}\\
&=\frac{1}{|z_{12}\bar{z}_{12}|^{\Delta}}\alpha^{\Delta}\bar{\alpha}^{\Delta}\Big|\alpha\bar{\alpha}\Big|^{-\Delta}e^{\pm i\pi \Delta}\tag{6}
\end{align*}

In (5) we used that we are considering the scenario where $z_{12}\bar{z}_{12}>0$ and hence this positive quantity can be factored out. In (6) we used that it must be the case that $\alpha\bar{\alpha}<0$ as we are considering the scenario where the conformal transformation changes the sign of $z_{12}\bar{z}_{12}$.  We therefore have a negative number to a power in the denominator and hence we incur a factor of $e^{\pm i \pi \Delta}$. Now one might think that the phase of the $\alpha^{\Delta}\bar{\alpha}^{\Delta}$ term might be able to cancel the $e^{\pm i \pi \Delta}$ so that (6) agrees with (3). However in order for the cancellation to actually occur, all of the starting $(cz_i+d)$'s, i.e. those featuring on the RHS of (1), would have to be equipped with $\pm i\epsilon$ prescriptions.

[1] tilde on an object means taking the universal cover thereof.

Comment: In order to show that (1) does not hold for all causal orderings you had to find the equation that does hold (at least for a 2pt function). So I think you know how to answer this.